# Problems with ggmap - register_google not found

Tags: r, api, google-maps, error-handling, ggmap

I have big problems to use ggmap since the API key is needed. I registered at google and have a valid API key, but I cant get ggmaps running.

I tried to install ggmap with devtools. I did this:

```
remove.packages("ggmap")
remove.packages("devtools")
remove.packages("googleway")
remove.packages("mapproj")

install.packages("rlang")
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")
```

But I always get this error code when loading devtools:

```
library(devtools)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’:
Object‘glue_collapse’ is not exported from 'namespace:glue' 

register_google(key = "mykeyABC")

Error in register_google(key = "mykeyABC"): 
could not find function "register_google"
```

Comment: does it help if you first install glue? `install.packages("glue")` then `install.packages("devtools")` then `devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")` then see if function is available with `?ggmap::register_google`